# Evaluate an Array and write it to a different sheet?

Tags: excel, vba

Can someone explain why this Array formula doesn't work? Thanks!

```
Dim myArray As Variant
Dim yourArray As Variant


    myArray = Sheets("db_main").Range("S2:S200").Value
    yourArray = Sheets("export").Range("A2:A200").Value

    If myArray < 4000 Then

        yourArray.Value = myArray.Value

    End If
```

Comment: myArray refers to a range, I don't think `myArray < 4000` makes sense

Comment: is there a way i can evaluate elements in an Array instead of evaluating a  cell one by one in a loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do need to iterate over every cell.

```
For Each c In Worksheets("db_main").Range("S2:S200").Cells
    If c.Value < 4000 Then Worksheets("export").Range("A" & c.Row) = c.Value
Next
```